# Put arrows in tree drawn with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-trees

I am starting to use LaTeX for a graph theory course I am following at uni. I managed to build this tree, I am only missing the arrows (that should be pointing downwards in all of the edges).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance=30mm/#1}]
\node [circle,draw] {1}
  child {node [circle,draw] {2}
    child {node [circle,draw] {5}}
    child {node [circle,draw] {6}}
    child {node [circle,draw] {7}}
  }
  child {node [circle,draw] {3}
  }
  child {node [circle,draw] {4}
    child {node [circle,draw] {8}}
    child {node [circle,draw] {9}}
    child {node [circle,draw] {10}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to define style for edges:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
level/.style={sibling distance=30mm/#1},
edge from parent/.style={->,draw}   % <----
                        ]
\node [circle,draw] {1}
  child {node [circle,draw] {2}
    child {node [circle,draw] {5}}
    child {node [circle,draw] {6}}
    child {node [circle,draw] {7}}
  }
  child {node [circle,draw] {3}
  }
  child {node [circle,draw] {4}
    child {node [circle,draw] {8}}
    child {node [circle,draw] {9}}
    child {node [circle,draw] {10}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Similar result you can achieve by use of the package `forest` dedicated to drawing tree diagrams:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
    circle, draw, 
    minimum size=1.5em,
    inner sep=2pt,
%
    s sep=3mm,
    l sep=7mm,
    edge={-Straight Barb} % arrows head defined in 'arrows.meta'
            }
[1
    [2
        [5]
        [6]
        [7]
    ]
    [3,fit=band]
    [4
        [8]
        [9]
        [10]
    ]
r
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Zarko, thank you for your answer. I tried to put your code (copy/paste) from \begin{tikzpicture} till the end but my document does not compile. Maybe is due to my documentclass? I have \documentclass[12pt, tikz]{article}

Comment: I do not know, what you have in your document's preamble. There must be also loaded packages which are used in my examples (`tikz` at first, `forest` and used library `arrows.meta` at the second one). Otherwise, solution is independent from used document class.